# Is there any way that we can detect android soft navigation bar in react native(expo )?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Is there any way in react-native to know if an android device has soft navigations keys (the bottom buttons). For example, in Xaiomi Mi 8 the navigations keys are configurable and can be removed.

In my use case, My view changes if the device navigations keys are shown or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module

```
react-native-detect-navbar-android
```

[Refer Here](https://github.com/lequanghuylc/react-native-detect-navbar-android)

This module tells if android device has soft navigation bar or not.


Hope this works for you !

Comment: No,I have to use this without detaching expo ,this library does not work with expo ,Thanks